# HTML 5 SQLite Offline DB

Tags: sql, sqlite, html

I've been working through this tutorial: http://www.mobilehtml5.com/post/401111526/tutorial-your-first-mobile-html5-app-offline-storage

I've been using it to create a simple db to record the money in arcade machines, with a table storing the name and the amount in each of the machines.

My problem is that I have no idea of the best method to easily edit the rows? html5rocks.com gave me a few ideas, but nothing appropriate.

Can anyone put me on the right track with this? I don't know the correct approach, is there some sort of cursor type way of doing this? or should i have a loop to load the values into input form boxes and then update these?

Any help would be brilliant, i've included the code below so you can see what i'm doing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>  
<head>
<title>Machine Total Calculator</title>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
  google.load("jquery", "1.4.1");
</script>
<script>

  var db = window.openDatabase("Machines", "", "Arcade Machines", 1024*1000);

 function insertMachine(name, amount) {
   db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO groupOne (name, amount) VALUES (?, ?)', [name,     amount]);
   });
  }

   function renderResults(tx, rs) {
    e = $('#status');
    e.html("");
    for(var i=0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) {
      r = rs.rows.item(i);
      e.html(e.html() + 'id: ' + r['id'] + ', Name: ' + r['name'] + ', Amount: ' +  r['amount'] + '<br>');
    }
  }


  function renderRecords(name) {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {

        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM groupOne', [], renderResults);

    });
  }


  $(document).ready(function() {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS groupOne(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name  TEXT, amount DECIMAL)', []);
    });


$('#machine_form').submit(function() {
insertMachine($('#name').val(), $('#amount').val());

     renderRecords();
     return false;
});


renderRecords();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" id="machine_form">
  <div>
    <input type="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Machine Name" size="30"/>
    <input type="number" current id="amount" placeholder="Amount" name="amount"  size="15" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add Machines" />
  </div>
</form>
<div id="status">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem: You have to use the same way as e.g. in the PHP+MySQL. You have to load the whole record into INPUTs value by value, remembering the ID of the record (for example in a hidden INPUT). In the handler of onclick event for some UPDATE button you fetch these values as well as the ID, and arrange the SQL UPDATE query ("UPDATE groupOne SET name=..., value=... WHERE id=...")

No, there are no "cursor way" in this SQL. Just remember the ID of the record and use it in WHERE clause in UPDATE.

Comment: ok, so i'm thinking add a button to where the rows are printed out which passes the id to an update function and add the ability to edit and update within that?  i tried this, but the id wouldn't pass along to the function:    e.html(e.html() + 'id: ' + r['id'] + ', Name: ' + r['name'] + ', Amount: ' + r['amount'] + '<a href="#" onclick="updateRecord('+['id']+')">e</a>' + '<br>');
        }